# How do I install TeX Live on Ubuntu 20.04 in order to use Gregorio

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, linux, gregorio

I wanted to install TeX Live on Ubuntu 20.04 in order to use Gregorio in Scribus, and used apt-get to do a full install, but it seems as though that may not be the best way to install it (for example, not all packages may be up to date). After installing it, I wanted to make sure that Gregorio actually got installed, but tlmgr gives a checksum error.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the best, most BS free way to install TeX Live? If it is not apt-get, should I uninstall it? I don't want to have to install and and uninstall it and reinstall it in a different way 20 times just to get it to work.
2. How can I make sure that everything is up to date and works properly?
3. How can I Gregorio to work in Scribus? I know that there are extra steps to take.

I will add, if it is not already obvious, that I am new to LaTex. For now, I mainly plan on using it with Gregorio in Scribus, but it may come in handy in other ways later, so I did a full install of TeX Live.

I hope that I have made this post correctly. If not, please feel free to correct me

Comment: apt version is probably fine. As with every other program on the linux distribution you have, there are newer versions available if you abandon the package manager and install an upstream version, but most of the time you don't need that

Comment: Is it normal, then, that tlmgr gives a checksum error? What about using Gregorio in Scribus?

Comment: `tlmgr` isn't so useful for that distribution, use `apt` I can't help with scribus but someone will answer

Comment: Thank you David. I was trying to see if Gregorio was installed, but it is. I am going to try to get it to work in Scribus, but there seems to be missing files. Gregorio is included in TexLive, but Gregorio's contrib folder seems to be missing. I could download thefiles I need from Github, but since I know next to nothing about LaTeX, I don't want to put them in the wrong place (I also don't want to put them in a folder that I may need to move at some point). This makes me wonder if there are other problems with my installation of TexLive, or if Gregorio doesn't need those files anymore.

Comment: I will add that the version of TexLive that I have is three years old (from 2019).

Comment: I don't actually understand your requirement. I know nothing about scribus but it doesn't use tex at all does it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I got someone to help me. You can use TeX within Scribus, yes. I prefer Scribus for most things (TeX/LaTeX etc. are only better at some things).

Answer (score 1):

From [the Gregorio documentation, re: Scribus.][1]

> There are also some additional files for Scribus which must be
> installed. These files are available in the contrib/ directory of the
> Gregorio sources, and also in the Git repository. These files are
> 900_gregorio.xml and gregorio.png. If you are under Windows, they are
> in C:\Program Files\Gregorio\contrib (assuming you have gregorio
> installed here).

I really don't know much about this, other than those being the first things to verify (the rest is available on the project website) and tbh, I couldn't get this to work. Fr Samuel (who is on here but is also available via the users' group and the main project repository) is much better at this, but it's a finicky feature, such that I largely abandoned Scribus for LaTeX.
[1]: https://gregorio-project.github.io/introduction-scribus.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just now saw your answer. I got someone to help my and it works fine. In the preferences (for Scribus), you have to go to External tools. If you scroll down, you will see other external tools in the render frame section. You need to add the files to the folder they are in (I don't remember if you have to back to Scribus' preferences after that or not). Note that the render frame will look blurry until you export as a PDF (in the export dialogue, make sure to check the box to incorporate PDF files).